# Faking a textarea with scrollbar and updating content

Tags: jquery, css, html

since I can not markup content inside  tags I want to create my own "custom" textbox.
The textbox should work as a kind of console, where the progress of battle (i.e.) is logged.
I first tried to use a div, within a div, within divs for each log, but when the divs inside the outer divs exceed the max-height, they ignore the surrounding divs.

Example: [image]

Even if this would work I still got the problem, that there is no scrollbar, since it's not a `<textarea>`.

I googled a lot, but the only thing I found where overwhelming tutorials for dynamic feedreaders etc.

What I am looking for is a simple "textbox" aka "console" with scrollbar which contents do respect the borders of that console.
Accomplished with jQuery.

Thank you very much!

**Solution:**

**Before**

```
<div id="battleLog" style="max-height:100px;height:100px;min-height:100px;">
    <div style="padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;">
        //content
    </div>
</div>
```

**After**

```
<div id="battleLog" style="max-height:100px;height:100px;min-height:100px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <div style="padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;">
        //content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what code do u have right now?

Comment: Add overflow:auto to your div. That should work, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting this css on your div

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Comment: Glad it helped you, happy logging battle stats. You can accept the answer if it was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Then in your jQuery, when the content of the div changes do this:

```
$('#theDiv').get(0).scrollTop = 10000000;
```

I'm not sure if that's the best way, but it's what I have working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could add a scrollbar to your div by changing the [overflow-y](http://www.css3.com/css-overflow-y/) property:

```
#div{
overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

i think it's a better option than a textarea because you can also format the text.